# How can you express the next two consecutive odd numbers in terms of x?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I'm trying to express the next two consecutive odd numbers in terms of x. How do go about this?

Precisely, given a number $x$ I want two smallest consecutive odd numbers $m,n$ such that $x<m<n$.

Comment: Be aware that you wrote two very different things in your question and your body.  Are you trying to express the next two consecutive odd numbers *in terms of x*, or are you trying to express x *in terms of the next two consecutive odd numbers*?  If $x$ is, say $5$, do you consider "the next two consecutive odd numbers" to be $5$ and $7$ or do you consider the next two consecutive odd numbers to be $7$ and $9$?

Comment: My error. I'm trying t express the next two consecutive odd numbers in terms of x. Edited to reflect.

Comment: That still doesn't answer the question of what exactly you mean by "next two consecutive odd numbers" is.  If $5$ is your number, do you want $7$ and $9$?  or do you want $5$ and $7$ (despite $5$ not being bigger than $5$).

Comment: @JMoravitz Yes, that is it. 7 and 9.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably $x$ is an integer.  We have two cases:  either $x$ is even or $x$ is odd.

In the case that $x$ is odd, then $x+2$ and $x+4$ will both be odd and will be the next two consecutive odd numbers.

In the case that $x$ is even, then $x+1$ and $x+3$ will both be odd and will be the next two consecutive odd numbers.

Answer (score 1):

Let $x$ an integer, then the next two odd integers are 
$$2\times\Bigl\lfloor \frac{x+1}{2}\Bigr\rfloor + 1
\qquad\text{and}\qquad
2\times\Bigl\lfloor \frac{x+1}{2} \Bigr\rfloor + 3.$$

Indeed, if $x = 2n$ where $n\in\mathbb{Z}$, then
$$
2\lfloor (x+1)/2\rfloor + 1 = 2 \lfloor n + 1/2 \rfloor + 1 = 2n + 1
$$
and if $x = 2n + 1$, then
$$
2\lfloor (x+1)/2 \rfloor + 1 = 2\lfloor n + 1 \rfloor + 1 = 2n + 3.
$$

Comment: I can't understand this due to my level of comprehension. But someone else definitely will.

Comment: Maybe doesn't you know the symbol $\lfloor \cdot \rfloor$. If $x$ is a real number, $\lfloor x \rfloor$ is the biggest integer less or equal to $x$. For example $\lfloor 2.7 \rfloor = 2$, $\lfloor -3.8 \rfloor = -4$ and $\lfloor x \rfloor = x$ for $x$ integer.